# Unable to perform a filter

Tags: r, tidyverse

Everything has been working fine until a few minutes ago. Below is a sample of the data set.

```
silence<-suppressWarnings
silence(library(tidyverse))
silence(library(nycflights13))
UAdaily<-flights %>% 
  filter(carrier=="UA")
```

To which I get the following error:

```
 Error in filter.default(., carrier == "UA") : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

This is happening in the data set I'm supposed to work with too. What is possibly wrong? 
Here is a `traceback call`

```
10: filter.default(., carrier == "UA")
9: filter(., carrier == "UA")
8: function_list[[k]](value)
7: withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
6: freduce(value, `_function_list`)
5: `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
4: eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
3: eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
2: withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
1: flights %>% filter(carrier == "UA")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this :

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)
data(flights)

flights %>% 
  filter(carrier =="UA") 
# A tibble: 58,665 x 19
# year month   day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay arr_time sched_arr_time arr_delay carrier flight tailnum
#    <int> <int> <int>    <int>          <int>     <dbl>    <int>          <int>     <dbl> <chr>    <int> <chr>  
# 1  2013     1     1      517            515         2      830            819        11 UA        1545 N14228 
# 2  2013     1     1      533            529         4      850            830        20 UA        1714 N24211 
# 3  2013     1     1      554            558        -4      740            728        12 UA        1696 N39463 
# 4  2013     1     1      558            600        -2      924            917         7 UA         194 N29129 
# 5  2013     1     1      558            600        -2      923            937       -14 UA        1124 N53441 
# 6  2013     1     1      559            600        -1      854            902        -8 UA        1187 N76515 
# 7  2013     1     1      607            607         0      858            915       -17 UA        1077 N53442 
# 8  2013     1     1      611            600        11      945            931        14 UA         303 N532UA 
[…]
```

Comment: Accepted as this might help if the causative package is not loaded.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that there is another `filter` function that goes by `filter{signal}`. Solved it by using `dplyr::filter`